# how to use concat function in case statement using jpa criteria query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, concatenation, select-case, criteriaquery

Iam concatenating string and expression in case statement when the condition is satisfied as below mentioned code.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cq = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<StudentRegistration> root = cq.from(StudentRegistration.class);
Expression<Object> str = builder.selectCase().when(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(StudentRegistration_.studentRegistrationGrade), 3),builder.concat("CDATA",root.get(StudentRegistration_.studentRegistrationGrade))).otherwise("-1");
cq.select(str);
em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Because of writing concat function in case statement iam getting below exception. I tried all possible ways by giving builder.literal() but iam unable to solve this problem. I have strucked at this problem since two days. please help me out.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: || near line 1, column 314 [select case when generatedAlias0.studentRegistrationGrade >=3  then :param0 || generatedAlias0.studentRegistrationGrade else :param1 end from StudentRegistration as generatedAlias0]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you set proper dialect for your DB?

Comment: I think, generated SQL is missing parenthesis. Post your configuration file here. Are you using latest version of JPA provider?
     (:param0 || generatedAlias0.studentRegistrationGrade)